# How to pop parent viewcontroller to draw at background before transform scale the current view to 0.5 %

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, transformation, uiviewanimation

I'm try to popViewcontroller with transform scale animation

according this code when it begin transform it present the black screen instead of the Parent View

how to fix this ?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                         self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f); 
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 
                     }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, because the view of the previous controller is not in the view hierarchy until `popViewControllerAnimated:` method is called and you call it after the animation finishes.

I don't think adding subviews directly to the view of the navigation controller is a good idea, but the following code should work for you.

```
UINavigationController* navigationController;
CGRect frame;

//keep a reference to the navigation controller as
//[self navigationController] won't work after pop is called
navigationController = [self navigationController];

//remember the frame of the view relative to navigation controller's view
frame = [navigationController.view convertRect:self.view.frame fromView:self.view.superview];

//pop this controller, this will add the view of the
//previous controller into the view hierarchy
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

self.view.frame = frame;
//add this view on top of the previous one 
[navigationController.view addSubview:self.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
                     self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f); 
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

By the way, `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` is not a correct constant for the options parameter. You should use the constants that start with `UIViewAnimationOption` for this method.